# Error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, build, web-config

I opened with **Visual Studio 2010** a solution with **3 subfolders**. One **website** containing files aspx and cs and the web.config. One **WSDL web reference** that contains XML files as well as app.config files. And one folder containing cs classes and a **csproj** file.

I didn't develop the solution. When I try to build the application I get the following error.

> Error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

I tried to move the web.config (or tjust the configuration part) in the root directory, I tried to modify the authorization type (set to Windows, I tried to set to None). No success. Anybody might help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was given by a wrong check out made by the source control SW (Visual SourceSafe)